# Regex match pattern not value

Tags: regex

String:

```
a = 10
b = 50
c = a + b
```

Regex:

```
([a-z]) = (\d+)|([a-z]) = ([a-z]) \+ ([a-z])
```

I want to match the first group **pattern** to the last  3 groups instead of it's value to avoid repeating it all over.

Something like

```
([a-z]) = (\d+)|\1 = \1 \+ \1
```

But instead of \1 evaluation to 'a' I want to see if is the same pattern.

Comment: what's your tool? sed, grep, python, java?

Comment: what about `c = b + a`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: No, he wants to avoid having to duplicate the `([a-z])` part of his regex (so as not to violate the DRY principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some regex engines (for example PHP's PCRE engine, Perl and Ruby) support [subroutines](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html):

```
preg_match('/([a-z]) = (\d+)|((?1)) = ((?1)) \+ ((?1))/', $subject)
```

Note that in order to keep capturing the contents of those subroutines, you need an extra set of parentheses. So `(?1)` acts as a "placeholder" for `[a-z]`, and `((?1))` captures that in a new capturing group.

If your language's regex engine doesn't, you may still be able to use string manipulation to implement subpatterns, though. For example, in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> letter = "([a-z])"
>>> regex = re.compile(r"{0} = (\d+)|({0}) = ({0}) \+ ({0})".format(letter))
```

Comment: Too bad Python can't do subroutines. I would be really useful. Is there a workaround to get the values just like the first example?

Comment: @f.rodrigues: Well, technically, I'm doing the string manipulation *before* constructing the regex (from the manipulated string). About Python: The alternative [`regex` module (PyPI)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) supports subroutines.

Comment: I know I can just put it inside another (), but I wonder if I can't get the first letter(the one before the '=') and place all of them in the same group, I tried using namedgroups (?P<letter>[a-z]) but it raises 'sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'letter' as group 4; was group 1'

Comment: Ah, yes, unlike .NET, Python's engine allows a named group to be used only once per pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If your GREP dialect supports it: use a Named conditional construction.

> `(?(<name>)then|else)` where `name` is the name of a capturing group and `then` and `else` are any valid regexes
>   (http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html).

The following regex initially matches either an initial lowercase or a set of digits. The match gets stored into the local capturing group #2 (lowercase) *or* #3 (digits). Then, the conditional instruction `?(2)` tests if group #2 matched anything. If so, the first half of the rest of the regex is tested, if not, the second half is.

```
\l = ((\l)|(\d+))(?(2) \+ \l| \+ \d+)
```

On a short test list

```
a = 10 + 15
b = 50 + b
c = a + b
```

this will match the first and third line but not the second.